# Carousel React Fluent UI does not render properly when have more than 8 thumbnails

Tags: reactjs

This problem is costing my sanity.
I want to use the React Fluent UI Carousel component with thumbnails and place it in the middle of my container, everything works fine till I add more than 8 slides. The carousel moves to the left side of the screen and eventually disappears from the viewport.

I am using the default code snippet from Fluent UI IS AVAILABLE HERE[Fluent ui thumbnail carousel](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.59.0/components/carousel/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#variations-carousel-thumbnails-example)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2T42.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, just overwrite the following properties:

```
.ln {
    width: 600px;
}

.ui-carousel__navigation {
  margin-top: -55px !important;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.nb {
    transform:none !important;
}

.ol {
    transform: none !important;
}

.nc {
    transform: none !important;
}
```